# how to get div inside of ul-li-a and make equal inside text of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a cached list inside search button and once I choose one of them it should trigger the menu and pick up the right one. However I could not figure out how to compare the `innerText` of a `div` with the chosen one from the search area. Both `a` and `div` should be visible.

```js
$(function() {
  function filterTable(tbl, term) {

    $("ul li a", tbl).show();
    $("ul li a", tbl).each(function(i, r) {
      if ($("div:eq(0)", r).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        $(r).hide();
      }
    });
  }

  $("#txtsearch").autocomplete({
    source: ["ERP", "Finans Muhasebe", "Banka"],
    select: function(e, ui) {
      filterTable($("table"), ui.item.value);
    },
    minLength: 0
  }).keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $("ul li a").show();
    }
  }).click(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete('search', "");
  })
});
```

```css
.wrap_atletas_interno img {
  line-height: 0;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 11px;
  border: 3px solid #d0d2d6;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li .nome_86_atleta {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  background: #d0d2d6;
  color: #243769;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 0px;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li.atleta_atual {
  border: 3px solid #c91700;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li.atleta_atual .nome_86_atleta {
  background: #c91700;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li.ultimo {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="txtsearch" type="text" placeholder="Search Here..." />
</div>
<ul class="menu-content openMenu">
  <li class="menuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <div class="iconBox color-ER">E</div><span class="title">ERP</span><span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="0"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-cube fa-lg"></i><span class="title">Finans Muhasebe</span><span class="arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Cari<span class="arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.list_caris">
                  <div class="objectText">Cari İşlemler</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.list_company_extre">
                  <div class="objectText">Cari Extre</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.payment_track&amp;money_info">
                  <div class="objectText">Borç Alacak Dökümü</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_add_debit_claim_note">
                  <div class="objectText">Dekont Ekle</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_add_cari_to_cari">
                  <div class="objectText">Cari Virman Ekle</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_add_cari_rate_valuation">
                  <div class="objectText">Kur Değerleme İşlemleri | CARİ</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_upd_account_open">
                  <div class="objectText">Dönem Açılışı</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Banka<span class="arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_account">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka Hesapları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_actions">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka İşlemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_virman">
                  <div class="objectText">Döviz Alış Satış Virman İşlemi</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_assign_order">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka Talimatları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_invest_money">
                  <div class="objectText">Para Yatırma</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_gelenh">
                  <div class="objectText">Gelen Havale</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_creditcard_revenue">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartı Tahsilatları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_credit_card_expense">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartıyla Ödemeler</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_get_money">
                  <div class="objectText">Para Çekme</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_gidenh">
                  <div class="objectText">Giden Havale</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_payment_credit_cards">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartı Hesaba Geçiş</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_creditcard">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_bank_rate_valuation">
                  <div class="objectText">Kur Değerleme İşlemleri | BANK</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_autopayment_export">
                  <div class="objectText">Otomatik Ödeme İşlemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_term_deposit">
                  <div class="objectText">Vadeli Mevduat Hesaba Yatır</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_autopayment_import">
                  <div class="objectText">Otomatik Ödeme İşlemleri Dönüşleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.interest_revenue">
                  <div class="objectText">Vadeli Mevduat Getiri Listesi</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_bank_branch">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka Şubeleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_bank_account_open">
                  <div class="objectText">Hesap Açılışı</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_bank_types">
                  <div class="objectText">Bankalar</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_bank_pos">
                  <div class="objectText">Pos Tanımları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_pos_operation">
                  <div class="objectText">Otomatik Sanal Pos Kuralları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_credit_payment_types">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartı Ödeme/Tahsil Yöntemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=settings.list_pos_relation">
                  <div class="objectText">Sanal Pos Tanımları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.wodiba_bank_actions">
                  <div class="objectText">WoDiBa Banka İşlemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cagatay07/x7amLdhs/8/)

**UPDATED:**

Not all sub-menu elements should be visible, except for the `class="objectAdd"`.
if the user has typed 'Cari', all relevant 'Cari' which has objectAdd class must be visible. An example picture has been added.

[image]

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question. I've edited it for you in this case. Also, is your goal to hide the `li` elements which *do not* match the text entered in to the box?

Comment: Thanks for editing, I will include next time. yes if text is entered and matched, it should hide other li elements. However if user entered 'Cari', all relevant 'cari' should be visible, such as 'Cari İşlemler', 'Cari Extre'...@RoryMcCrossan @Twisty

Comment: Your selectors are off for this structure. Also 'Cari' is not one of the Autocomplete options.

Comment: It's unclear what should be hidden or shown. Based on your Source, it's just the `.sub-menu` elements?

Comment: @Twisty, I updated the question. Not all `.sub-menu` elements should be visible, except for the one which has `class="objectAdd"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're no longer using a `table`, you have to consider how that effects the HTML Structure. This will change your functions and some of the selectors.

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function filterGroup(el, term) {
    $("ul > li", el).show();
    $("ul > li", el).each(function(i, r) {
      if ($("a > div", r).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        $(r).hide();
      }
    });
  }

  $("#txtsearch").autocomplete({
    source: ["ERP", "Finans Muhasebe", "Banka"],
    select: function(e, ui) {
      filterGroup($(".sub-menu").parent(), ui.item.value);
    },
    minLength: 0
  }).keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $("li").show();
    }
  }).click(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete('search', "");
  })
});
```

```css
.wrap_atletas_interno img {
  line-height: 0;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 11px;
  border: 3px solid #d0d2d6;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li .nome_86_atleta {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  background: #d0d2d6;
  color: #243769;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 0px;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li.atleta_atual {
  border: 3px solid #c91700;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li.atleta_atual .nome_86_atleta {
  background: #c91700;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.wrap_atletas_interno li.ultimo {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="txtsearch" type="text" placeholder="Search Here..." />
</div>
<ul class="menu-content openMenu">
  <li class="menuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <div class="iconBox color-ER">E</div><span class="title">ERP</span><span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="0"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-cube fa-lg"></i><span class="title">Finans Muhasebe</span><span class="arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Cari<span class="arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.list_caris">
                  <div class="objectText">Cari İşlemler</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.list_company_extre">
                  <div class="objectText">Cari Extre</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.payment_track&amp;money_info">
                  <div class="objectText">Borç Alacak Dökümü</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_add_debit_claim_note">
                  <div class="objectText">Dekont Ekle</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_add_cari_to_cari">
                  <div class="objectText">Cari Virman Ekle</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_add_cari_rate_valuation">
                  <div class="objectText">Kur Değerleme İşlemleri | CARİ</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=ch.form_upd_account_open">
                  <div class="objectText">Dönem Açılışı</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Banka<span class="arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_account">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka Hesapları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_actions">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka İşlemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_virman">
                  <div class="objectText">Döviz Alış Satış Virman İşlemi</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_assign_order">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka Talimatları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_invest_money">
                  <div class="objectText">Para Yatırma</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_gelenh">
                  <div class="objectText">Gelen Havale</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_creditcard_revenue">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartı Tahsilatları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_credit_card_expense">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartıyla Ödemeler</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_get_money">
                  <div class="objectText">Para Çekme</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_gidenh">
                  <div class="objectText">Giden Havale</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_payment_credit_cards">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartı Hesaba Geçiş</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_creditcard">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_bank_rate_valuation">
                  <div class="objectText">Kur Değerleme İşlemleri | BANK</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_autopayment_export">
                  <div class="objectText">Otomatik Ödeme İşlemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_term_deposit">
                  <div class="objectText">Vadeli Mevduat Hesaba Yatır</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_bank_autopayment_import">
                  <div class="objectText">Otomatik Ödeme İşlemleri Dönüşleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.interest_revenue">
                  <div class="objectText">Vadeli Mevduat Getiri Listesi</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_bank_branch">
                  <div class="objectText">Banka Şubeleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.form_add_bank_account_open">
                  <div class="objectText">Hesap Açılışı</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_bank_types">
                  <div class="objectText">Bankalar</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_bank_pos">
                  <div class="objectText">Pos Tanımları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.list_pos_operation">
                  <div class="objectText">Otomatik Sanal Pos Kuralları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=finance.list_credit_payment_types">
                  <div class="objectText">Kredi Kartı Ödeme/Tahsil Yöntemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=settings.list_pos_relation">
                  <div class="objectText">Sanal Pos Tanımları</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=bank.wodiba_bank_actions">
                  <div class="objectText">WoDiBa Banka İşlemleri</div><span class="objectAdd"></span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```